# Sorting a list based on another attribute in another list

Tags: c#

I have the objects as below:

```
public class CustomerSequence
{
    public string CustomerName  { get; set; } 
    public int Sequence { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Component { get; set; } 
}
```

Let's say I have 2 Lists Object

```
Customer:                             CustomerSequence:
Id         Name        Component      CustomerName         Sequence
1          AAA         AAAAAA         AAA                  2
2          BBB         BBBBBBB        BBB                  4
3          CCC         CCCCC          CCC                  1
                                      DDD                  3
```

As you can see there is no **DDD** in List.

I want to sort the List **Customer** based on the List **CustomerSequence**

Result is:

```
Customer:
Id         Name        Component
3          CCC         CCCCC
1          AAA         AAAAAA
2          BBB         BBBBBBB
```

Anyone can help me please.

Comment: What's the expected behaviour if there is no matching row in the sequence table?

Comment: @BobVale I will not let it happens since I select List<Customer> based on the CustomerSequence.CustomerName.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join both sequences on customer name, then order by sequence value:

```
from c in customers
join cs in customerSequences
    on c.Name equals cs.CustomerName
orderby cs.Sequence
select c;
```

Lambda syntax is not that beautiful, and it will look like

```
customers.Join(customerSequences, 
               c => c.Name, cs => cs.CustomerName, (c,cs) => new { c, cs })
         .OrderBy(x => x.cs.Sequence)
         .Select(x => x.c)
```

Internally join uses lookup for second sequence, which is much more effective then linear search with `Where`.

---

If it is possible that there is no CustomerSequencs matching customer, or there is more than one match, then use group join:

```
from c in customers
join cs in customerSequences
    on c.Name equals cs.CustomerName into g
orderby g.Select(cs => cs.Sequence).FirstOrDefault() 
select c
```

This query uses 0 form missing sequences, and first matched value if there is more than one sequence for customer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Customer.OrderBy(x => CustomerSequence.Where(y => y.CustomerName == x.Name)
                                      .Select(y => y.Sequence)
                                      .FirstOrDefault())
```

Alternatively you can use a join which would be better if the source was a database

```
var sorted = 
from c in customer
join csj in customerSequence on c.Name equals csj.CustomerName into customerSequenceJoined
from cs in customerSequenceJoined.DefaultIfEmpty()
orderby cs == null ? 0 : cs.Sequence
select c;
```

The `cs == null ? 0 : cs.Sequence` deals with the case when there is no matching record in the sequence collection.  You could use `int.MaxValue` if you want these items to appear last.

Answer (score 1):

Use Join

```
var customers = from cust in Customer
                     join cust_seq in CustomerSequence
                     on cust.Name equals cust_seq.CustomerName         
                     orderby cust_seq.Sequence
                     select cust;
```

Comment: Hi, I believe is orderby cust_seq.Sequence.

Comment: Yep you are right, overlooked that and supposed that u would get it ;)

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use a dictionary for this sort of thing.

```
var customerSequence =
    customerSequences
        .ToDictionary(x => x.CustomerName, x => x.Sequence);

var sortedCustomers = 
    customers
        .OrderBy(x => customerSequence[x.Name])
        .ToList();
```